# Skip Weekends between days, months and weeks in looping with php

Tags: php

Am asking users to input a start date and an end date to generate a schedule for payment, am looping within the two dates to generate the schedule on weekly,daily and monthly base on users selection.

```
   $f_repayment_date = "2015-01-01";
   $mat_date = "2015-10-01";
    while (strtotime($f_repayment_date) < strtotime($mat_date)) {

        $f_repayment_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($f_repayment_date)));
      $count++;


      //calculate interest on outstanding balance


      if ($balance < $payment) {
          $payment = $balance;
          $interest_amount = $interest_amount ;
          $principal = $payment - $interest_amount;
           $due = $payment + $interest_amount;
       }

      $balance = $balance - $payment;

       if ($balance < 0) {
         $principal = $principal + $balance;
         $interest_amount  =  $interest_amount;
         $balance   = 0;
      } 
     $sql = mysql_query("insert into loan_schedule values (NULL,'$f_repayment_date','$account_number','$contract_code','$loan_product',
     '$loan_amount','$frequency','$loan_term','$interest','$payment','$principal','$interest_amount','$balance','$due','$count','','$due','$active_loan')");
       }  
    } while ($balance > 0);
```

Comment: Where are you stuck, what have you tried? What errors do you get and what are you trying to achieve, please update your post with this information. Maybe add an example too.

Comment: @ TeeDeJee want to skip weekends between the dates. Thanks

Comment: have you tried google? this question already has tons of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `date` function:

```
$weekends = array(6, 7);
$day = date('N', strtotime('2015-10-01'));

if (in_array($day, $weekends)) {
    continue; // skip this day
}
```

You should also put your dates in quotes, otherwise you'll get `2013` instead of `'2015-01-01'`:

```
$f_repayment_date = '2015-01-01';
$mat_date = '2015-10-01';
```

Comment: Please where do I place the looping?